# Sqoop not working on Mac

Tags: sqoop

I have installed Apache sqoop on Mac using homebrew with all it's dependencies. But it seems sqoop is not doing anything at all.

Even if I just type 'sqoop help' it outputs -

```
Warning: /usr/local/Cellar/sqoop/1.4.6_1/libexec/bin/../../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
```

And no help is printed.

Other commands like snoop-import is there too but does not seem to be doing anything at all when executed.

Does sqoop not work on Mac or is there anything wrong on my setup?

Thanks.

Comment: That warning is expected, but `help` should definitely do something

Comment: This is strange. It seems like all sqoop commands just being no-op :(

Comment: What if you download it separately from Apache site and run it? Are you able to run other Java based programs?

Comment: Thanks. It's solved now. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I installed it from this location - 
`http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/apache/sqoop/1.4.7/`
its working fine. Though I had to set some environment variables properly. Thanks.

Comment: can you please guide me which are variables we need to set to work in mac?

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: as you said, you have setup some environment variables.  which are variables you setup that i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.7
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.7
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_PREFIX
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME
export HADOOP_YARN_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.7
export HCAT_HOME=/usr/local/opt/hive/libexec/hcatalog
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.7/etc/hadoop
export ZOOKEEPER_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/zookeeper/3.4.12
export HBASE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hbase
export SQOOP_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/sqoop
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/hive/2.1.0/
```

Also, not all version of Hadoop is compatible with all version of HIVE/HBASE/SQOOP. You need to install right versions.

Hope this helps.